# The type or namespace name 'PostEffectsBase' could not be found

Tags: unity-game-engine

I upgraded my unity project from 2020 to 2022.3.17f1. And it throws me this error (look below). Any help would be appreciated.

`Assets\Standard Assets\Effects\ImageEffects\Scripts\CameraMotionBlur.cs(9,37): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PostEffectsBase' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Thanks,

I tried looking for solution in Unity forum. However, I couldn't find anything that I can apply to my project.

Comment: we can take some mild stabs in the dark that  you dont have some of the dependencies it needs..  but whether thats urp, hdrp, post processing.. who knows. you need to go look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go in a two years version jump you always have to be aware that in the meantime quite a lot might have happened. Something might be deprecated / renamed.

Especially also in those packages. As long as they don't have at least a stable `1.0.0` release you can always expect them to change quite a lot between versions.

`PostEffectsBase` seems to be from the `Unity Toon Shader` package.

=> You can see that it [existed in version 0.6](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.toonshader@0.6/api/UnityChan.ImageEffects.PostEffectsBase.html). But when you switched Unity version it was most probably bumped to a newer version where this doesn't exist anymore.

My guess: Most probably because the shader already does more things on its own now so scripts are not required anymore

---

I think a solution might be found [here](https://discussions.unity.com/t/problem-assets-standard-assets-image-effects-pro-only-cameramotionblur-js-102-20-bce0005/73734)

> You’ve probably imported an asset that contains image effects scripts from an older version of Unity.
>
> Re import “Image Effects (Pro Only)” from the Assets->Import Package menu and it should fix the problem.

This is from 2013 and still refers to the Unitscript implementation - but as yours are also the standard assets it might be worth a shot

Comment: I see. Thank you! I def gave it a try. Turns out, it doesn't support newer versions (yet). For now, my solution is to downgrage back to 2020. 